# Can not add Google Suite account to Normal Gmail's "Send mail as". Error 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted

Tags: gmail, email

I have many work email and would like to simplify the work by add it to my Gmail's "Send mail as", so that I only have to check and process mail in 1 mailbox.

But when I add an email `me@my-company01.com` (Google Suite) to `me@gmail.com`, it throws error (image below).
**What can I do for solve it?**

Note:

- I could successfully login to web with username/password provided
- I've confirmed with my-company01's IT Dept, they said that "no restrictions at all".
- I've enabled "Less secure apps" in my `me@my-company01.com` setting
- I've successfully add another company email (`me@my-company02.com` - Office_365) in `me@gmail.com`)

[image: Error 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After disabled and re-enable `Less secure app`, it works now.

---

Update 2020-09-23

After some tries, I found the final solution for "check mail from multiple account (me@comp1, me@comp2...)  from 1 email only (me@gmail.com)"

1. Login to `me@comp1.com`
2. Go to **Settings / See all settings / Forwarding and POP/IMAP**
3. Set it to Forward mail to me@gmail.com
4. Login to me@gmail.com
5. Go to **Settings / See all settings / Account & Import**
6. Add `me@comp1.com` to **Send mail as**, remember to choose "*Reply from the same address the message was sent to*"

[image: set it to Forward mail to me@gmail.com]
[image: Add me@comp1.com to Send mail as]